# Any current bakechain voting solution?

Tags: voting

Any chance that Bakechain users will be able to vote on the current proposals, also what option do we have if it’s not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bakechain will include voting, but there is no set timeframe on that. Currently the only method for voting is via the command line tool (tezos-client), but other wallets and tools should add support for this in future too.